# Understanding SQL Server keys and comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my SQL Server 2014, I have a table with a `varchar`/`nvarchar` (tested both, the outcome is the same!) column that is the primary key. In fact, the column values have to be unique and are used for about 50% of the selections, so it seems to make sense to make it the PK. The column is right now set to Collation `<database default>`, which should be Latin1_General_AS, not sure whether collation is the issue here.

Into that varchar column I insert a value with special character, in this example, the Polish(?) `Osioł` (but I want to support all characters which are allowed in LDAP CN Names in the future):

```
INSERT INTO Names (Name, Mail) VALUE('Osioł', 'osiol@test.local');
```

When I now try to update that value:

```
UPDATE Names SET Mail='osiol2@test.local' WHERE Name='Osioł';
```

it returns zero changed rows. Which, for me, up to now meant that the key is not yet in use, and that I am able to insert. Which I subsequently try, and fail with the error

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Names'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Names'. The duplicate key value is Osioł.

The same goes for selects:

```
SELECT * FROM Names WHERE Name='Osioł';
```

won't return the row.

How can I select/update that row using the PK with special chars?

Comment: by the looks of it you have a primary key on that table and that record already exists. try and find the definition of the PRIMARY KEY constraint to narrow down the problem and find the record which causes the complaint.

Comment: also INSERT INTO Names (Name, Mail) VALUE('Osioł', 'osiol@test.local'); should be INSERT INTO Names (Name, Mail) VALUES('Osioł', 'osiol@test.local');

Comment: I woudl also suggest that neither Name nor email make a good primary key. Names are not guaranteed to be unique and emails are unique but can be reused by different people and frequently change. Names changed as well and  a PK is something that should be unchanging especially if you have child tables using that as as FK.  You should have an autonumber field as the PK (it will perform faster in joins too) and a unique index on email as well as regular index on name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to Sean Lange's answer your insert should also be:

```
INSERT INTO Names (Name, Mail) VALUES(N'Osioł', 'osiol@test.local');
```

because the `N` specifies it to be a Unicode character.

then this will work:

```
UPDATE #Names
  SET  Mail = 'osiol2@test.local'
WHERE  Name = N'Osioł';
```

and if you are using a select it has to be:

```
SELECT #Names.Name
    , #Names.Mail
FROM   #Names
WHERE  Name = N'Osioł';
```

Below should explain what is happening:

SAMPLE DATA:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Names') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
       DROP TABLE #Names;
    END;

CREATE TABLE #Names(Name NVARCHAR(50)
               , Mail NVARCHAR(50));

INSERT INTO       #Names(Name
                   , Mail)
VALUES
      (N'Osioł'
     , 'osiol@test.local');


INSERT INTO       #Names(Name
                   , Mail)
VALUES
      ('Osioł'
     , 'osiol@test.local');
```

SHOW INSERTED VALUES IN THE TABLE:

```
SELECT #Names.Name 
    , #Names.Mail
FROM   #Names;
```

[image]

UPDATE THE UNICODE VALE WITH POLISH CHARACTER ONLY:

```
UPDATE #Names
  SET  Mail = 'osiol2@test.local'
WHERE  Name = N'Osioł';
```

SHOW RESULTS:

```
SELECT #Names.Name
    , #Names.Mail
FROM   #Names
WHERE  Name = N'Osioł';
```

[image]

```
SELECT #Names.Name
    , #Names.Mail
FROM   #Names
WHERE  Name = 'Osioł';
```

[image]

As you can see without the `N` the server looks up the `VARCHAR` value rather than the unicode `NVARCHAR`

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly state that your string literal is nvarchar. Notice the N at the beginning of the string.

```
UPDATE Names SET Mail='osiol2@test.local' WHERE Name=N'Osioł';
```